Can the completion of a local domain which is not a field be a field?
I would like to prove/disprove the following claim:

Let $A$ be an equicharacteristic local domain, and denote by $\widehat{A}$ its completion with respect to its maximal ideal. If $\widehat{A}$ is noetherian and $\dim A \geq 1$, then $\dim \widehat{A} \geq 1$.

Of course, if $A$ is noetherian, then $\dim A = \dim \widehat{A}$ and the claim is obviously true. So if we want to seek for counterexamples, we have to look for them among the nonnoetherian rings (see below for other extra sufficient conditions).
On the other hand, when trying to prove the claim, this is where I got:
Denote by $\mathfrak{m}$ and $\widehat{\mathfrak{m}}$ the maximal ideals of $A$ and $\widehat{A}$, respectively. Suppose that $\dim \widehat{A} = 0$. Then, $\widehat{A}$ is artinian, and in particular $\widehat{\mathfrak{m}}^n = \widehat{\mathfrak{m}}^{n+1}$ for $n \geq n_0$. By Nakayama, $\widehat{\mathfrak{m}}^n = 0$. Since $\mathfrak{m}\widehat{A} \subseteq \widehat{\mathfrak{m}}$, it follows that $\mathfrak{m}^n \widehat{A}= 0$. This means that $\mathfrak{m}^n$ is contained in the kernel of $A \to \widehat{A}$. In turn, the kernel is $\bigcap \mathfrak{m}^k$, so we conclude that $\mathfrak{m}^n = \mathfrak{m}^{n+1}$ for $n \geq n_0$. This implies that the map $A \to \widehat{A}$ is surjective with kernel $\mathfrak{m}^{n_0}$. In particular, $\widehat{A} \cong A/\mathfrak{m}^{n_0}$, and also $\left(\widehat{A}\right)_\mathrm{red} \cong A/\mathfrak{m}$.
However, I don't know how to go on from here... For instance, if $\mathfrak{m}$ was finitely generated, then, by Nakayama, we would get that $\mathfrak{m} = 0$; i.e. $A$ would be a field, contradicting that $A$ has positive dimension.
Similarly, if $\bigcap \mathfrak{m}^k = 0$, then $\mathfrak{m}^{n_0} = 0$. Since $A$ is reduced, $\mathfrak{m} = 0$, and we would reach to the same contradiction. [This is remarked in the comments by YCor]
These cases aside, does anyone have any clue?
Thank you for your time, any help in any direction will be appreciated :)
Edit
As Laurent's nice example shows, the claim is false. But now the natural question is: does the claim hold if we furthermore impose that $\mathfrak{m}^2 \neq \mathfrak{m}$? As Achim points out, this new condition is equivalent to assuming that $\widehat{A}$ is not a field.

There are positive-dimensional local domains $(A,\mathfrak{m})$ with $\mathfrak{m}=\mathfrak{m}^2$, e.g. valuation rings with value group $\mathbb{Q}$ (such as the integers of $\mathbb{C}_p$ or the ring of Puiseux series over a field). As you say, for these rings we have $\widehat{A}=k$.

@LaurentMoret-Bailly Thanks a lot!

@LaurentMoret-Bailly Your nice example made me curious and I added a second question to my post. Feel free to contribute :)

To answer your edit, can't you just use Laurent's example, but add one more power series variable to the radical that commutes with the rest? Then the square of the radical misses this new variable but contains the square.

Rather assume $\bigcap\mathfrak{m}^n=0$?

@YCor Yeah, with that extra assumption the claim is true. Following my discussion in the post, $\mathfrak{m}^n = 0$. Since $A$ is a domain, this implies that $\mathfrak{m} = 0$; i.e. $A$ is a field. Hence $A$ has dimension zero, against the hypothesis. I was aware about that before, that's why I wanted to focus on a more subtble condition ;)

I think the question in the title is easily seen to be equivalent to $\mathfrak{m}^2=\mathfrak{m}$, by using that we have a surjective map from the completion to $A/\mathfrak{m}^2$. Just to clarify, you're instead asking whether the completion can be zero-dimensional (and not just a field)?

@AchimKrause That's a good point. The completion $\widehat{A}$ is a field if and only if $\mathfrak{m}^2 = \mathfrak{m}$. Although I wrote the title of the post in that way, I was really thinking about the dimension of $\widehat{A}$ (not really if it was a domain or not). So the relevant question is the one in the grey box (which was solved by Laurent) and the new edit. Thanks for clarifying!
